# How to locate what PST file and specifically what folder within the PST an email is in?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I managed to move all of the items from my inbox into one of the folder's within one of my 3 PST files.  I know the emails were not deleted because searching my mail folders will display them, but I have no idea what folder they are in so I can move them back to my inbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it a hack, I don't know...  But, after locating one of the emails via outlook search I decided to mark it as "Unread".  By doing this, I was then able to look through the folders in my PST and found where a new message appeared and was able to recover all messages...

Comment: You can also use the flagging feature see "Add or remove a flag" http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP052432271033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try **[Kernel for Outlook](http://www.pstviewer.net/)**

the evaluation version should suffice to view/search the content of PST files.

> Evaluation version of the software
>   displays preview of recovered emails
>   and other items in list like structure
>   but do not allows to save them.